# R making a list of dataframes

Tags: r, function, slice

I have a rather large dataframe and I am using slice() to chop it into the sections I need. I tried writing a function that I thought could accomplish what I was trying to do.
This is how I was originally doing things:

```
Alabama <- slice(Crime_US, 1:31)

Alaska <- slice(Crime_US, 40:70)

Arizona <- slice(Crime_US, 79:109)

Arkansas <- slice(Crime_US, 118:148)

California <- slice(Crime_US, 156:186)
```

Here is some output for Alabama:

```
Year  Population `Violent crime to… `Murder and nonneglige… `Legacy rape /1` `Revised rape /… Robbery `Aggravated assa…
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>              <chr>                   <chr>            <chr>            <chr>   <chr>            
1 1970  3444165    10185              404                     637              NA               1731    7413             
2 1971  3479000    10835              524                     661              NA               2005    7645             
3 1972  3510000    10994              496                     660              NA               2407    7431             
4 1973  3539000    12390              468                     751              NA               2809    8362             
5 1974  3577000    13338              536                     811              NA               3562    8429             
6 1975  3614000    14201              577                     738              NA               4446    8440
```

This is how I wanted to do it. Here is some code to clarify.

```
Crime_US <- read_excel("crimeAllStates.xlsx", skip=9)

states_vec <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "D.C.", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennslyvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming")


counter <- 1
m <- 1
n <- 31
makeMyStates <- function(df) {
  states_vec[counter] <- slice(df, m:n)
  counter <- (counter + 1)
  m <- (m + 39)
  n <- (n + 39)
}

sapply(Crime_US, makeMyStates)
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("slice_") : no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I tried googling the error to no avail and I do not have much experience with R.

Comment: `split(Crime_US, rep(states_vec, each = 31))`

Comment: I really wanted to use this, unfortunately the dataframe has 9 blank lines in between states, so it seems like only the first tibble comes out correct. thank you though

Comment: `split(Crime_US[!is.na(Crime_US$Year), ], rep(states_vec, each = 31))`

Comment: oh man I really like your solutions, I wish I knew what I was doing wrong, but it just isn't working for me. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to resort to arbitrary breaks based on the values in `m` and `n`, I think trying to populate a list might help.

Your line: `states_vec[counter] <- slice(df, m:n)` is trying to populate a character vector with a data frame which is why you are getting this error.

a for loop with a list might be a way around this (although it's not very tidyverse):

```
    state_crime <- list() 
    m <- 1
    n <- 31

    for (i in 1:length(states_vec)){

      state_crime[[i]] <- slice(Crime_US, m:n) %>%
                          mutate(state = states_vec[i])

      m <- (m + 39)
      n <- (n + 39) 

      }
```

and then name each element of your list using the `states_vec` list or just bind the rows to make a new data frame.

`names(state_crime) <- states_vec`

`bind_rows(state_crime)`

Comment: While this is not a very tidyverse way, it is clever and it suited my needs with one additional piece of code: list2env(state_crime ,.GlobalEnv). Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create group of 39 rows and there is no other way to identify each State, we can create a sequence of index and use `Map` to subset it

```
m <- 1
n <- 31
no_rows <- nrow(Crime_US)

Map(function(x, y) Crime_US[x:y, ], seq(m,no_rows, 39), seq(n,no_rows, 39))
```

---

A `tidyverse` way would be

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2(seq(m,no_rows, 39), seq(n,no_rows, 39), ~slice(df, .x:.y))
```

Comment: I like the elegance of this, unfortunately it is throwing an error and also the tibbles arent assigned to the states names like I had needed.

Comment: @JayWehrman So there is no pattern using which you can correctly identify where one state ends and other starts ?

Comment: Unfortunately the best I have is this: I know that the information for the first state starts at row 1 and ends at 31, then skip 9 rows, next state begins on row 40 and ends on row 70, skip 9 and this pattern continues.

Comment: @JayWehrman Since, I do not have your complete data I don't know exactly when a particular state starts or ends. It is based on the information you provide. My solution creates a subset of data based on the index. Run this in the console and make sure that these are the start indexes `seq(m,no_rows, 39)` and these are the end index `seq(n,no_rows, 39)` of every state.